# the jqueryui datepicker “create” of event don't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, datepicker

In my project which uses with jQueryUI's datepicker of plugins,

but in this code,the "create" event never fires,

you can check the documentation in official site:

> http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker

in the *Options* tab.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    create: function(event, ui) {
        alert("ppp");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation lies (as noted by Nick). If you look at `jquery.ui.widget.js` in the source, you'll see this:

```
$.Widget.prototype = {
    // ...
    _createWidget: function( options, element ) {
        // ...
        this._trigger( "create" );
        this._init();
    },
```

So the create event is handled by the jQuery-UI widget factory so it *should* be supported by all of the widgets. If you look at `jquery.ui.button.js`, you'll see the widget factory in use:

```
$.widget( "ui.button", {
    options: {
        //...
```

and you will find that the button widget *does* fire the create event. If you look at `jquery.ui.datepicker.js`, you won't find any `$.widget` but you will find a reminder for something to be done when the datepicker is converted to the widget factory:

```
// TODO rename to "widget" when switching to widget factory
_widgetDatepicker: function() {
    return this.dpDiv;
},
```

The datepicker doesn't use the widget factory and it doesn't implement the create event itself.

The beforeShow event does work though so maybe you can use that.

Quick demo (open your console please): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kn3hq/

Comment: to my surprise that the documentation is wrong,so I'll find other way to do my project,thx!

Comment: @Rupert: You could try the version from github (https://github.com/kbwood/jquery-ui) that Nick found, I don't know how stable it is though.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an open ticket regarding this.

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6935

Comment: +1 for find the (disappointingly old) bug. The underlying problem is that the datepicker doesn't use the widget factory and the create event comes from the widget factory.

Comment: I knew about the bug because I've had the same problem before. I actually thought there was some fixed code going around, but it was for a really old release jQuery (1.4 iirc), so I didn't think it worth going to the trouble of hunting it down.

Comment: That's close enough. The datepicker looks like it was kludged into jQuery-UI by force, maybe that rewrite that has been going on for a couple years will sort it out.

Comment: That one should trigger the "create" event as it uses the widget factory. Any idea how stable it is or even if it is being actively developed? Doesn't look like anything as happened with it since spring 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish with a temporaly solution, use "dom inserted event" in "master page" to catch datepicker creation:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function (event) {

    //  If is a datepicker element
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('ui-datepicker-calendar')) {         

        //  Check only new elements
        $('.hasDatepicker:not(.controlClass)').each(function (i, obj) {

            //  Add class for avoid current obj in next datepicker creation
            $(obj).addClass("controlClass");

            //  Do what you want with $(obj)

        });
    }
});
```